# finding a general way of aggregating elements of a vector

Tags: r, vector, aggregate

I have a vector of exactly 5 elements. The elements of the vector contain numbers which are larger than 100 and smaller than 100. these elements represent the number of points in a certain region in space.

I would like to find a general way of aggregating the elements which are smaller than 100, with their neighbors.

The rules are the following:

1. I can only join neighbors (2 is a neighbor of 1, 3 and 1 are neighbors of 2, 4 is the only neighbor of 5...).
2. I cannot aggregate more than 3 elements. So for example if elements 1,2,3,4 of the vector are all smaller than 100, I can only aggregate 1,2,3 or 2,3,4 between themselves (and not with 5, because this would again be more than 3).
3. if the elements to aggregate are 1,2,4, what I can do is aggregate 1 and 2 with 3, and 5 with 4.

I am trying to write a general function to do this, but for the moment what I have done is generate all the possible combinations and told R what to do in each case (like I have done above), which is long and tedious.

for example:

```
v = c(100, 30, 50, 100, 20)
```

so in this case, my result would be:

```
v1 = c(130, 170)
```

from aggregating elements (1+2, 3+4+5).

In general, there can be more than one way to aggregate, depending on the neighbors from each side.

Any creative ideas of how to write this up neatly?

Comment: *...which are larger than 100 and smaller than 100*... Also reproducible example and expected output, as well as your attempt

Comment: Could you provide a specific example of what you want to do?

Comment: What about `c(10, 100, 20, 100, 10)`? I think the assignment of the 20 is ambiguous with your rules.

Comment: your'e right, but it doesn't matter - there is some freedom here. So for example the answer could be either c(130, 110) or c(110, 130)

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant but I think it will work:

```
v = c(100, 30, 50, 100, 20)
v2 <- v
which_ <- which(v == 100)
v2[which_]   <- seq(sum(v==100))
v2[which_-1] <- seq(sum(v==100))[which_-1 != 0]
v2[(which_+1)[which_+1 <= length(v2)]] <- seq(sum(v==100))[which_+1 <= length(v)]
aggregate(v,list(v2),sum)$x
# [1] 130 170
```

Comment: not bad, thanks. However what about the following case: `v = c(20, 20, 50, 100, 100)`. Here it gives a wrong result :(